# Creating User with Rails API and JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm testing out a very simple API in Rails to see if I can create a user from it locally using the Chrome plugin Postman (REST Client extension).

In my rails app, I've set up a folder/namespace for my API, and whenever I try to create my user, I get the following error:
Missing template api/v1/users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "PATH/app/views"

I'm using Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0

I'm posting a screenshot below of what I'm posting:

[image: Screenshot 1]

```
module Api
     module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
        class User < ::User
            # add any hacks
        end

        respond_to :json

        def index
            respond_with User.all
        end

        def show
            respond_with User.find(params[:id])
        end

        def new
            @user = User.new
        end

        def create
            @user = User.create(user_params)
            # respond_with(@user)

            if @user.save
                # render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
                redirect_to @user
            end
        end

        private

            def user_params
              params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location) if params[:user]
            end
    end
  end
end
```

So based on my user_params, I should be able to create a new user, correct?
Please let me know if you need any additional info and I'll do my best to respond ASAP!
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create user using API.

1) First you need to put proper resources in your routes.rb:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
     resources :users
    end
    namespace :v2 do
    # ... if needed
    end
  end

  root to: 'users#index'
end
```

2) You need to create a RESTfull-style controller to process requests. Here how your action 'create' may be implemented.

```
def create
  respond_with User.create(fio: params[:fio], phone: params[:phone], region: params[:region], updated_at: Time.now)
end
```

Example of 'create' with respond_to:

```
def create
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render text: "Your data was sucessfully loaded. Thanks"}
      format.json { 
                   User.create(... params ...)
                   render text: User.last.to_json  # !
                  }
    end
  end
```

See documents about [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) and [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) if you need something special to respond.

Also can be helpful railscasts episodes about API building: [#350](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast) and [#352](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)

P.S. folder/namespace/v1/**users_controller** shall be the same as class name in your module Api

P.S.2 You can observe my app, where you can probably find something helpful (same as your app - simple API for records creating) - [myApp](https://github.com/DavydenkovM/GetLead.git)

Example of users_controller (controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb):

```
#encoding: utf-8

    module Api
      module V1
        class UsersController < ApplicationController # Api::BaseController
          before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:create, :index]

          respond_to :json

          def index
        #respond_with

            respond_to do |format|
              format.html {render text: "Your data was sucessfully loaded. Thanks"}
              format.json { render text: User.last.to_json }
            end
          end

          def show
            respond_with User.find(params[:id])
          end

          def create
            respond_with User.create(access_token: params[:access_token], city: params[:city], created_at: Time.now, phone: params[:phone], region: params[:region], updated_at: Time.now)
          end

          def update
            respond_with User.update(params[:id], params[:users])
          end

          def destroy
            respond_with User.destroy(params[:id])
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful. I'm making some leeway but still kind of stuck...Do you mean that I should have two users_controllers? One in the main app and one in my API folder? Because right now I have 2 and am having trouble distinguishing what should go where.

Comment: Yes, you can have as much users_controllers as you need, because they are in a different namespaces (one is your main users_controller and others in controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb, controllers/api/v2/users_controller.rb, ... etc.).

Comment: I just meant you have a respond_to and a respond_with example and I wasn't sure if you meant to put one in the API version and one in the other..

Comment: Well, i hope it is clear now. If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Actually, I have a related question: Now I have a private def for user_params, which seems to be working, except for the arrays that I need to submit. In forms, I usually use checkboxes, but in this instance I'm trying to assign genres to a user. (:genre_ids => []) How would I submit this via JSON (or as a URL param?)

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` dose not return, so your `create` method will keep looking for template to render, and then find there is no matching template.

To fix, you need to explicitly return `redirect`

```
 if @user.save
   return redirect_to(@user)
 end
```

You also need to pay attention to the default url of @user. It's better to assign a named path explicitly in this case, say `redirect_to(user_path(@user))`