# Inserting Array with Form/JSON to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

So I'm currently working on an API, based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320913/creating-user-with-rails-api-and-json/20323268?noredirect=1#comment30366005_20323268) that I asked:

I would like to be able to add an array of genre_ids to my user upon creation.
Currently in my API Users Controller, I have my function:

```
def create
    respond_with User.create(user_params)
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location, :genre_ids => [])
end
```

So I go to create my user with a RESTful extension I have, and creating a user normally works perfectly without genres. 
But as soon as I add the genres, it doesn't fail, but it also doesn't save correctly. 
I'm just trying to simulate how it would be created with a form or with url params. Would it be something like:
1&2&3
1,2,3
[1,2,3]?

Any suggestions on the proper way to do this?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your two choices in this case would either to `POST` raw JSON:

```
{
    "genre_ids": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

Or, if reworking your back end to handle that doesn't make sense, simply:

`1,2,3` will work in the URL-encoded form value. If you find the comma is causing you trouble, you could urlencode the value *before* it is `POST`ed, which would convert `,` to `%2C`.